# Please suggest 3D Report Creation tool that have a good look and feel?

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting

I want to create 3D reports which have a good look and feel.  I am using VS 2008 and SQL server 2008. Is there any way of creating 3D or 4D reports in SQL server 2008 or can I use the crystal reports package that is bundled with .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go for additional tools, try Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Report Builder's 3D effects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239315.aspx

Else you can look into charting solutions by Infragistics http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage.aspx#Overview

cheers

Comment: Do we need to install infragistics to for going to the second option ?